# How to set subscription/membership plan as default?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am using Woocommerce Subscription plugin. 
I have two types of plans right now. 
1. Is paid 
2. Free 
When user registers on my site, I want every user to show default free membership subscribed to that account in beginning until it upgrades manually later.
Is there any Hook which I can use?

I have tried checking in Plugin settings but I didn't find anywhere if I can set a subscription plan 'as default'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create an order, then create a subscription, link the order to the subscription using WooCommerce classes. Below is the link where I found my answer:

wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/202873/

The response given by Jeremy Warne worked for my website's logical flow.